# Check if a program is installed and how can I start it if it is not in the menu?

Tags: installed-programs

I have tried installing both **spideroak** and **google earth** by downloading the `.deb` packages from their websites. They finish and Ubuntu Software center installed them like normal and they showed up in my drop down menus. But they didn't show up in the installed software list. In addition, when I click on them (from the menu), nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run them from the console:

- Open a Terminal
- type the name of the program in the terminal and press enter
- observe the output for possible hints, what is going wrong